# How to save simulation data using for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, saving-data

I am simulating several data sets using for loop in R and saving the data sets in text files in a folder. Since I need to analyze these data sets, I am importing these data from the folder to R and doing my analyses. I am wondering if there is any way to do both simulation and analysis by keeping them in R as data frames instead of saving and importing. Here is my code:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\datageneration")

kitem<-10
N<-100
disc<-rnorm(k,0,1)
diff=rnorm(k,0,1)

irtp<-function(t,a,b,pexp)
{
    pexp<-1/(1+exp(-b*(t-a)))
    pexp
}
for( iter in 1:20) 
{
    X<-mat.or.vec(N,kitem)
    P<-mat.or.vec(N,kitem)
    for(i in 1:N)
    {
        theta<-rnorm(N,0,1)
        assign(paste0("theta", iter), theta)
        filename1 <- paste (" theta",iter ,".txt ", sep ="")
        write.table( get(paste0("theta",iter)) , file = filename1 , row.names =FALSE ,col.names = FALSE )
        for(k in 1:kitem)
        {
            P[i,k]<-irtp(theta[i],diff[k],disc[k],pexp)
            X[i,k]<-ifelse(runif(1)<P[i,k],1,0)
            assign(paste0("X",iter), X)         # HERE'S THE PART THAT I NEED HELP
            filename2 <- paste ("X",iter ,".txt ", sep ="")
            write.table( get(paste0("X",iter)) , file = filename2 , row.names =FALSE ,col.names = FALSE )
        }
    }
}
```

All I want to do is just to use the generated data files (e.g., theta1, theta2, theta3..., theta20) by calling their names(e.g., theta1). Since I am generating thousands of data sets, I would like to know if I can do it without using write.table then read.table functions. I will be very appreciated if you can help me.

Comment: Are your simulations vectors (like in your sample code above) or more complex structures? Do you need to keep the data, or would id be OK to just produce, use and discard them?

Comment: Thanks for asking vaettchen. Actually my code is more complex than this one. I am also generating  matrices which include 100 rows and 10 columns in addition theta vectors. I just posted that code for simplicity. I still want to save the files in a folder as shown in my code. But after analyses I would delete some of them which do not meet my criteria. Simply, I would like to do both way at the same time. I like to keep data sets in a file and also use them without importing. Sorry about my English. I hope you understand what I want to do.

Comment: You are overwriting the "dat" file 19 times.

Comment: Not sure whether I fully understand what you are trying to do but I guess you need to change the naming in the inner loop, probably by combining `iter` and `kitem` into filename2; otherwise you keep overwriting your stuff.

Comment: As a result I would like to obtain two sets. First set is the theta vectors (e.g., 20 theta vectors: theta1 to theta20). Second set is X matrices (e.g., 20 X matrices: X1 to X20). Each of X matrices should contain 10 items(kitem)/columns and 100 rows(N). I am OK with theta part since they're vectors but stuck with X matrix part. Are you sure it solves the problem if I could combine iter and kitem?

Comment: What do you need the `for(i in 1:N)` loop for? You are creating and overwriting N times without benefit (or is it me who doesn't see the obvious?). Also, `pexp` is not defined in the sample code. Your function definition does nothing to or with `pexp`. You could simply write `irtp <- function( t, a, b ){ 1 /( 1+exp( -b*( t-a ))) }`.

Comment: I have edited my list answer below to reflect your X needs. I appreciate the list is not really what you want but still you mihgt consider...  --  there are also a]some bugs in your code that I have commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to reflect the need for the X matrices:
Create a list of 20 + 20 items with your simulation data, and name the members accordingly:

```
kitem<-10
N<-100
disc<-rnorm(kitem,0,1)  # not ( k, ... )
diff=rnorm(kitem,0,1)   # not ( k, ... )
pexp <- 1                   # ??? - not needed here

# the list that takes all the produced data
mySim <- as.list( NULL )

# function definition reduced to the necessary
irtp <- function( t, a, b ) {  1 / ( 1 + exp( -b * ( t -a ) ) ) }

for( iter in 1:20 )
{
  # create two matrices to be filled later
  X<-mat.or.vec(N,kitem)
  P<-mat.or.vec(N,kitem)

  # create and name the theta component
  theta = mySim[[ iter ]] <- rnorm( N, 0, 1 )
  names( mySim )[ iter ] <- paste ( "theta", iter, sep ="" )

  # fill and save the matrices
  for( i in 1:N )
  {
    for( k in 1:kitem )
    {
      P[i,k]<-irtp(theta[i],diff[k],disc[k] )  #  don"t need this: ,pexp)
      X[i,k]<-ifelse(runif(1)<P[i,k],1,0)
    }
  }
  mySim[[ 20 + iter ]] <- X
  names( mySim )[ 20 + iter ] <- paste ( "X", iter, sep ="" )
}
```

You can save the list altogether as an R object, if you want that.

Now you can adress each simulation be name:

```
head( mySim$theta3 )
[1]  0.96068066  0.01966067 -1.25682531 -0.15128916 -0.75950710 -1.22243883
```

You can add matrices, dataframes etc. to the list

```
mySim$tau1 <- c( "lists", "take", "everything" )
```

You can selectively save list members with the corresponding file name:

```
filename <- paste( names( mySim )[3], ".txt", sep = "" )
write.table( mySim$theta3, filename )
```

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: definitely that's what I had in my mind. Thanks a million! Thanks for your time and patience...

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what do you want to do , but I think here `replicate` is what you need.

```
ss <- replicate(20,replicate(N,rnorm(N,0,1)))
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Suppose I generated 20 data sets (theta1 to theta20). I can save them into a folder using write.table function. Then I can import them bask into R using read.table function. That's OK. But I cannot see them in R when I call their names (e.g., theta1) after generation. I just want to skip write.table/read.table part. Simply, I just don't want to save and import, I just want to use data sets directly after generation by calling their names.

Answer (score 0):

The objects in those Rda files will all have the same name, 'theta', so you will not be able to load them without having any earlier versions overwritten. If you want to save them without names, you can use `saveRDS` and `readRDS` giving them varying names. If you want to give them different names before then get `save()`-ed, then use `assign` and then save in the manner you are currently using.

All that said, I would be a lot easier to make a list of twenty such objects with varying names and then save them all at once and load them all at once.

```
N=10
for ( iter in 1:3) 
{
      theta<-rnorm(N,0,1)
    assign(paste0("theta", iter), theta)
    filename1 <- paste (" theta",iter ,".txt ", sep ="")
    write.table( get(paste0("theta",iter)) , file = filename1 , row.names =FALSE ,col.names = FALSE )
}

> ls(patt="theta")
[1] "theta"  "theta1" "theta2" "theta3"
```

Comment: Great! That's what I have been looking for. Many thanks DWin. You made my day and saved my days or weeks;)

Comment: I think I should have put my whole code in order to solve my problem. Your solution was OK for theta vector. I thought the game was over but for the matrix part in my code I tried the same thing as I did for theta vector but could not get what I wanted. I also want to have X1, X2... X20 data sets in the inner loop. I may be doing a silly mistake. I tried to put it into several different places but could make it. I will be very appreciated if you can tell me how to correct my code(see updated code please) in the creating X part.